# Trying to get a sample Node.js application working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get a basic chat application running that uses node.js, express, and socket.io.
I've successfully got everything running to where I don't get any errors on the server side or client side.  However, the application doesn't work.
I am supposed to be able to open two browser windows and chat with myself.  I type in the text box to send a chat message to myself but nothing is received.  I am pretty sure nothing is sent either.  Using FireBug I don't see any new requests being sent over the network.  However, using Firebug I also see that all the requested include files are being served correctly to the browser.  There are only three - index.html, socket.io.js, and jquery.min.js.

Here is a link to the tutorial I am using:
http://philmunt.com/post/15643013618/node-js-socket-io-chat-application-tutorial

With the server.js file I modified it a little to get it working.  The main problem was that my browser was not receiving socket.io.js so I added a path to allow server.js to know where it is.  Like this:
app.get('/sio/socket.io.js', function (req, res) {........
Could that be my problem?

Here is the server code - server.js:

```
var express = require('express'), app = express(), http = require('http'), server = http.createServer(app), io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// listen for new web clients:
server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});         

app.get('/sio/socket.io.js', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile('/root/nodejs/node-v0.10.0/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js');
});     

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) { socket.broadcast.emit('message', data); socket.emit('message', { text: '<strong>'+data.text+'</strong>' });   
 });   
 });
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<html> 
  <body>
    <script src="/sio/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
          $('#chat').append(data.text + '<br />');
        });

        $('#send').click(function () {
          socket.emit('sendMessage', { text: $('#text').val() });
          $('text').val('');
        });

      });
    </script>

    <div id="chat" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black">

    </div>    

    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="send">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app.get(socketstuff) part, you don't need that as the js file is made available for you with

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and change your socket variable to:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```